# Persist data between successive cron job calls

Tags: linux, cron

I have a linux cron job that runs every 10 minutes. It basically runs a ruby script that fetches some data and does calculations. I want to pass data from one successful execution of the cron to the next. Right now I am thinking of simply storing the data in a file and reading it from there.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: There are probably alternative ways to accomplish this, but I have a hard time imagining that any of them are better. But, of course, that depends on exactly what metrics you use to define "better"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron itself does not provide persistent storage (not counting crontabs themselves), so you will have to store state manually - in a file, database or even shared memory segment.